# How to make last link not have :after

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this CSS

```
.pages a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #1e1e1e;
font-weight: bold;
display: inline;
padding-left: 8px;
}

.pages a:after {
content: "|";
padding-left: 8px;
}
```

I want the content in `a:after` have the `|` after the last "a". How would I do that? I tried using `:last-of-type`, but it didn't work.

It currently looks like this

```
1 | 2 | 3 |
```

Comment: Why not change it to before and keep it off of the `:first-child`?

Comment: I tried it can it didn't work.. .pages a:before:first-child {
 content: "";
 padding-right: 0px;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this

```
/*Other style goes here*/

.pages a:last-child:after {
    content: "";    
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/2JF4w/1/)

Comment: Just remember that the `a` **must** be the last child of the parent, so if you add any more content to the parent, this will fail.

Comment: also note that `:last-child` is unsupported in IE<9, if that matters to you

Comment: @numbers1311407, I'm aware of that and hope `OP` knows that too.

Comment: my intention was to make @Anthony aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
.pages a:after {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
.pages a:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '|';
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVv7f/1/)

This will add the padding to all of the `.pages a`, and it will add the `|` for any `a` that isn't the last child of `.pages`

Answer (score 0):

What about this, `last-of-type` will work

```
.pages a:last-of-type:after{
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: I want the link to show still just not the content that I add.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want, I guess:

http://jsfiddle.net/VVv7f/

```
.pages a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.pages a:after {
    content: "|";
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.pages a:last-child:after {
    content: ""; /* this line overwrites your "|" with empty "" */
}
```

Comment: Just remember that the `a` **must** be the last child of the parent